# How would the end-user access the Sphinx generated documentation for a Python package?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have developed a package in python, and I have created documentation for it using Sphinx.

The relevant part of the folder structure is shown below:

```
my_package
  setup.py
  my_package
    my_module.py
  docs
    index.rst
    _build
      html
        index.html
```

The package will be hosted at some location in the LAN that's referred to by `PYTHONPATH`. My end user will be accessing my package with just `import my_package`. They wouldn't know where the documentation (or the package for that matter) is located. Using `help(my_package)` is only going to show the user the documentation within the module.

So, I am wondering how to allow my end-user to access the index.html file? I thought of coding in a method that opens the html file from a specified location, but I didn't like the idea of hardcoding in a path. Is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: Why not add the path to Sphinx-Documentation to the docstring of the module?

Comment: @ChristianSauer I thought of that, but since the docs are part of the package, I was hoping that there'd be some way of allowing the user to call up the ``index.html`` from wherever the package is installed.

Comment: Honsetly, what stops you from deploying the docs with your package?
I have done just that for one of our internal packages - sure it would not do it for a public package, but for our internal package, it was the easiest option to get the docs deployed

Comment: @ChristianSauer, I will be deploying the docs with my package, but I just want to avoid telling the user: go to wherever you installed the package, and look in docs > _build > html and open the index.html file to access the documentation. That doesn't seem very neat...

Comment: What kind of editor do you use? If pycharm, you can add additional doc sources for packages. If not, the easiest is to add an url to the docstrings of the package, methods and classes. it's not uncommon, numpy does exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, documentation is deployed separately to the package. For example the pandas repository (which includes the source code for the documentation in .rst files) is held in [Github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas), but the built documentation is available at [its own url](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/).

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @pkqxdd-s suggestion:

You can easily obtain the path to documentation within modules of `my_package`

```
# my_module.py

def get_docs_index_path():
    import os
    my_package_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    docs_index = os.path.join(my_package_root, 'docs', '_build', 'html', 'index.html')
    return docs_index
```

Now you could add the path to `my_module` or `my_package` docstring, so that users who call `help(my_module)` will get something like

```
... 
# original my_module docstring
...

See sphinx docs at <path to your index>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307696/how-to-put-a-variable-into-python-docstring) to learn how to add the path from `get_docs_index_path()` to the docstring.

Answer (score 0):

So if your only concern is you don't know where your module will be installed, you can figure that out by calling `your_module.__file__`(see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269795/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-python-module-sources)). In addition, you can also make use of `os.path` module. For example, calling `os.path.dirname(your_module.__file__)` may return the path to the folder where your `docs` folder is. You can then modify the path accordingly to access the .html file.