# Including a docstring in another docstring

Tags: python, docstring

Problem: I want to use one docstring in another docstring.

Suppose I have the following snippet:

```py
def window(dimensions: tuple):
    '''
    Function to create an app window and return it

    PARAMETERS
    ----------
    dimensions : tuple
        The width and height of the window to create

    RETURNS
    -------
    display.Window
        Class to implement a screen           # Make this equal to Window.__doc__ 
    '''
    class Window:
        '''
        Class to implement a screen
        '''
        def __init__(self, dimensions: tuple):
            pass
    return Window(dimensions)
```

I want to automatically set the docstring for `window` to include the docstring for `Window`

I read that you can set the docstring manually, like so:

```py
window.__doc__ = "".join((window.__doc__, Window.__doc__))
```

But it is only executed when the function is called.

Also, I could use decorators, but is there a simpler intuitive way to do this?

**Bonus:** Is there a way to decide exactly where in the docstring I can include another?

**EDIT:** So, it looks like there is a duplicate suggestion to this question, but since I specifically asked without decorators, that does make my question *somewhat* different. Also, my use of nested class in `window` means that any attempt to change `__doc__`:

1. inside of `window`: will not occur until function is called.

   outside of `window`: will not run as `Window` is nested.

So this rules both these methods out, as things stand.

But the answer of course has to be one of these. So the answer is a duplicate, not the question. :P

Therefore, I had to restructure my code. See below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put a variable into Python docstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307696/how-to-put-a-variable-into-python-docstring)

Comment: Could you please explain which method you mean.

Comment: I mean that you are asking the same thing: how to put a variable (namely `Window.__doc__`) in a docstring. There are several answers to the question, so if no one satisfies you, most probably it is impossible to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `@aparpara`, I found that answer (which didn't show up when I searched it online), and it made me realise there is (possibly?) no solution to my specific question.

Therefore, I had to remove the nested class to be able to access it outside the function.

Here is the final version.

```py
# module display_module.py

class Window:
    '''
    Class to implement pygame's screen
    '''
    def __init__(self, dimensions: tuple):
        pass

def window(dimensions: tuple):
    '''
    Function to create an app window and return it

    PARAMETERS
    ----------
    dimensions : tuple
        The width and height of the window to create

    RETURNS
    -------
    display.Window
        {0}
    '''
    return Window(dimensions)

window.__doc__ = window.__doc__.format(Window.__doc__.strip())
```

Still open to any answers to the old question!